# Output from resultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, collections

The below code gets refcursor from SP and iterates to and add to ArrayList. the code runs fine in test env but in higher env, it gets stuck at 1st debug statement in the while loop. No exceptions traced. If I execute SP independently in SqlDeveloper it returns me 1 record. Can someone help to find the issue?

```
Connection connection = null;
ArrayList viewArrayList = new ArrayList();
int sqlErrorNumber = 0;
String sqlErrorMessage = "";
CallableStatement cs = null;
ResultSet rs1 = null;
int cnt = 1;



ArrayList viewArrayList = new ArrayList();
    try {
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                              jdbcURL, jdbcUserName,
                              jdbcPassword);       

        cs = connection.prepareCall("begin PROC_VIEW_AC(?,?,?); end;");
        cs.registerOutParameter(cnt++, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
        cs.registerOutParameter(cnt++, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);  
        cs.registerOutParameter(cnt++, OracleTypes.CURSOR); 
        cs.execute();
        cnt=1;
        sqlErrorNumber = cs.getInt(cnt++);
        sqlErrorMessage = cs.getString(cnt++);

    if(sqlErrorNumber == 0)
    {
        rs1 = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(cnt++);   
        System.out.println("In method11 rs1 --- "+rs1.toString());

        while(rs1.next()){
                System.out.println("Inside while loop"+rs1.getFetchSize()+"---");
                DocGenModel caseMod =  (DocGenModel) new BeanProcessor().toBean(rs1, DocGenModel.class); 
                System.out.println("Inside while loop after cast .. ");
                viewArrayList.add(caseMod);
                System.out.println("Inside while loop after adding to arraList");
            }
        System.out.println("In method11 end of while --- ");
    }
    else{

             System.out.println("Error in  PROC_VIEW_AC Procedure :"+sqlErrorMessage);   

    }

        System.out.println("viewArrayList size ... "+viewArrayList.size());

    } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception is  "+e.getMessage());


                }
finally{
    if(null != rs1) {try{rs1.close(); rs1=null;}catch(Exception e){}}                
        if(null != cs) {try{cs.close(); cs=null;}catch(Exception e){}}
        if(null != connection) {try{connection.close(); connection=null;}catch(Exception e){}}
    }

 return viewArrayList;
```

rs1.getString(1) ->gives the 1st column value. So it appears to get the record but not able to typeCast to docGenModel.

Comment: `rs1.getFetchSize()` within the print statement is suspicious.  Is the same driver version used in all environments?

Comment: @Andrew yes its the same driver.

Comment: in docGenModel instead of rs1 try rs1.toString(1)

Comment: @ Abhijeet Padwal  what is toString(1)?